# Интерпретатор Python не видит библиотеку encoder

Tags: python, pip, encoder

Бьюсь с установкой библиотеки encoder - и она даже устанавливается. Однако при попытке импортировать упорно дает ошибку:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encoder'

Уже и pip до последней версии обновил, и всё никак. Причем та же проблема в Google Colab. Может, найдется рецепт побороть неодолимый сбой?

Comment: pip freeze что показывает? Операционная система? Запустить с логами `pip install encoder --log LOG_FILE`, чего говорит здесь?

Comment: @Dmitry он показывает наличие модуля Encoder. А сбой в строчке `from encoder.params_data import *`

Comment: Encoder то с большой буквы пишется? дайте ссылку на модуль с pypi.org/. Может вот так `from Encoder.params_data import *`

Comment: @Dmitry когда указываю с заглавной буквы, то ошибка - `No module named 'RPi' `. Ссылка на модуль - https://pypi.org/project/Encoder/

Comment: Значит модуль встал, с этим разобрались. Далее ОС какая у вас? Если винда, то `pip install python3-rpi.gpio`, для Linux `sudo apt-get install python3-rpi.gpio`

Comment: @Dmitry у меня Windows 10. А по установке ошибка -

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-rpi.gpio (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3-rpi.gpio`

Comment: Да, я вам написал команды для установки нужной зависимости. И я думаю вы поняли, что надо использовать при импорте `Encoder` с большой буквы. [Доп модуль доки](https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/)

Comment: Тогда вот так `pip install RPi.GPIO`

Answer (score 1):

По порядку:

1. убедиться, что модуль установлен

```
pip freeze
```

2. Почитать документацию по модулю. И мне кажется, что ошибка может закраться просто в опечатке, поскольку

```py
import Encoder
```

с большой буквы (если я тот модуль нашел)

3. Убедиться, что модуль предназначен для вашей версии `Python`
4. Если проблема с установкой можно ловить по логам

```
pip install Encoder --log LOG_FILE
```

**UPD**

В комментраиях разобрались, что сам модуль установлен. Проблема была в опечатке импорта.

```py
# не верно
from encoder.params_data import *

# верно
from Encoder.params_data import *
```